# Can't register any Kubernetes cluster to Google Anthos - 'Unknown Error'

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-anthos

I can't add a GKE (standard or autopilot, doesn't matter) to my Anthos Environ any more.  However, I was able to register existing GKE clusters within and outside the current gcloud project last week.

The steps that I took are pretty straightforward - I just followed the steps listed here https://cloud.google.com/anthos/multicluster-management/connect/registering-a-cluster

I verified my account has all the required IAM roles and the necessary APIs are all enabled.  That's why I was able to add a few standard and autopilot GKE clusters last week in the first place, and there was no change in terms of roles and APIs.  It just stopped working.

**Steps I followed:**

1. create a standard GKE cluster (a zonal with Workload Identity enabled)
2. Go to the Anthos Clusters page
3. Click Register existing cluster
4. Let it create a new service account
5. Leave the membership name as suggested
6. Click Submit
7. Cloud Console shows 'Unknown Error'

After the 'Unknown Error' message, nowhere shows any further information about what went wrong.  I created a fresh new project and tried the same but it shows the exact same error.  It is quite frustrating.  Is anyone experiencing the same?   Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you check if your trial is not over? At least I have the same error when it has ended for me. Take a look at the Anthos Dashboard, there should be a line `Your trial has ended. Subscription plans are available, which may help you save money.`

Comment: @Jakub  I have active subscription even though it's a trial.   

`Your trial ends in 6 days ($757.64 credit). Pay as you go and subscription plans are available. Learn more`

Answer (score 2):

I see you've opened a ticket on [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/184423917) for that issue, and it ends up as a GUI issue. I'm posting this answer as community wiki so other users could find the answer here if they would have same issue.

---

As mentioned by @Pralove Tandukar on above Public Issue Tracker

> Most probably the issue is with registering cluster from cloud console(UI). I have created internal consult about this issue with the GKE Product Team. But I cannot guarantee any ETA of its resoultion.

Currently the workaround for that is to use **CLI**.

Below are the commands used to register a cluster to google anthos that were verified and confirmed it works correctly with the **CLI**.

```
gcloud beta container hub memberships register MEMBERSHIP_NAME \
--gke-uri=GKE_URI \
--enable-workload-identity


gcloud container hub memberships register MEMBERSHIP_NAME \
--gke-uri=GKE_URI \
--service-account-key-file=SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY_PATH
```